# ReactJS nested inline styles

Tags: css, inheritance, nested, reactjs, components

I have a component named `SearchBar` in ReactJS

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div style={{width:'100%',position:'0',backgroundColor:'darkOrange'}}>
                <div style={[styles.dataBlock,styles.header]}>
                    <h1>MOVIE</h1>
                </div>
                <div styles={[styles.dataBlock,styles.searchForm]}>
                    <input style={[styles.dataBlock,styles.searchForm,styles.searchField]}
                        type="text" placeholder="Enter search term"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Here is `styles`:

```
var styles = {
    dataBlock: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        margin: '0 auto',
        fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    header: {
        width: 'inherit',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
    },
    searchField: {
        width: 'inherit'
    },
    searchForm: {
        width: '90%',
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto'
    }
};
```

It seems that the styles don't work, it is shown that the `input` textform doesn't have `width:90%` as I declare in `styles`. I want to use style inheritance so that in `style` I put in an array of inline styles. Have I got something wrong here? How can I inherit styles in ReactJS?

Comment: have a look at the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Comment: I did have reference from it. It says too little and doesn't have about what I'm stuck. Please read my question again, I want to se style inheritance? How can I inherit styles?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html),

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with **an object whose key is the camelCased version of**
>   **the style name, and whose value is the style's value**, usually a string

It clearly states that `style` needs to be an object of key-value pairs, not an array. There is no magic behind it. The style object can be composed in vanilla JS or with some utility libraries like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/), [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/), jQuery, anything that can fit your project.

```
// Vanilla JS
<div style={ Object.assign( styles.dataBlock, styles.searchForm ) }> ...
// Lodash
<div style={ _.assign( styles.dataBlock, styles.searchForm ) }> ...
```

Comment: In a React project, the vanilla `Object.assign` is probably more frequently used than `$.extend`.

Comment: This answer could be improved to help this exact question. Just copy pasting from the documentation misses points that would be helpful to the full context of the original question.